# Django Upload multiple images from a single button using forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Have been doing a lot of research but I cant seem to find much information on this.

I have a simple blog app where users are able to create a blog post via a model form. I would like users to be able to upload multiple images to their blog from a SINGLE button.

Most of the solutions I have found are using the admin panel or are just creating multiple buttons. None are using forms along with a button.

I figure the best way to go about this would be to create a new model with a FK to the blog model but I cannot seems to come up with a proper implementation. If you could please point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Something like...

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = RichTextUploadingField(blank=True, null=True)
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PostImages(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_images')
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Maybe you can create a model where each field is one image and when asking the user to upload the image in the form attached to that new model, the form will display an `Upload file` button for every field you added to your model.

Comment: This would work but if a user has 30 images to upload it would be impractical for them to have to click 30 buttons and select an image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you said multiple, I assume the number of images is unknown. So, you can create a different model for Image Upload. Then you can create a many-to-one relationship to the model where you store the number of images required. You can leverage Django's foreign key to do so. You may refer https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

You may follow the following steps -

1. Create two separate models 1 for taking the number of input storing the user id, etc. And the second one for storing the Image Upload Field.
2. Then you can declare a Foreign Key.
3. After this you render a form wherein you take the number of input images, once known you create that many objects for the image upload objects ( all linked to the same user ) and render a form where the user uploads them, then you can save them in the respective image upload fields.

You can always access the images from the custom user model or anything of that sort by using the foreign key.

I have assumed you have some kind of user models system since you mentioned users. If you are using the default django user model then you can expand it to incorporate the number of images field. This can be done by expanding the existing user model. Details - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/

Or you can just create one model to store just the number of images and declare user as an one to one model to that model. Something like this

```
class UserDetails(models.Model):

   user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   num_images = models.IntegerField(blank = True)
```

Comment: I think I get what your saying could you take a look at my update